# How to get the incomplete image shown on an image view with scroll and pan?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to make an instagram-like image selector, where you first select your image, then zoom and pan as you wish and click the save button.

Right now, I have a PinchToZoomContainer class, but I don't know how to get the image from the view after having moved it around a bit, rendering it incomplete in the view itself (not shown in its entirety). I only want what is shown in the view and no the complete image that getDrawable() gives.

```
internal class PinchToZoomContainer
{
    private ImageView view;
    private Bitmap btm;
    private enum Modes
    {
        NONE, DRAG, ZOOM
    }
    private Modes mode = Modes.NONE;
    private float oldDist;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();

    private float minScale = .1f; //Minimum scaling
    private float maxScale = .2f; //Maximum zoom ratio

    private PointF viewUpLeft = new PointF(),
                  viewDownRight;
    private PointF imgUpLeft,
                  imgDownRight;

    internal PinchToZoomContainer(ImageView imageView, DisplayMetrics metrics)
    {
        view = imageView;
        view.GetLocationInWindow(new int[] { (int)viewUpLeft.X, (int)viewUpLeft.Y });
        viewDownRight = new PointF(viewUpLeft.X + view.LayoutParameters.Width, viewUpLeft.Y + view.LayoutParameters.Height);

        btm = imageView.GetBitmap();
        if (btm.Width >= btm.Height)
            minScale = imageView.LayoutParameters.Height / (float)btm.Height;
        else
            minScale = imageView.LayoutParameters.Width / (float)btm.Width;
        maxScale = minScale * 4;

        view.Touch += ImgTouch;
        matrix.SetScale(minScale, minScale); //Start zooming out first
        int screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;
        view.ImageMatrix = matrix;
    }

    private void ImgTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageView view = sender as ImageView;
        switch (e.Event.Action & e.Event.ActionMasked)
        {
            //single finger
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
                start.Set(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY());
                mode = Modes.DRAG;
                break;

            //double finger
            case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:
                oldDist = Distance(e.Event);
                if (oldDist > 10f)
                {
                    savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
                    mid = Middle(e.Event);
                    mode = Modes.ZOOM;
                }
                break;
            //finger up
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
            case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                mode = Modes.NONE;
                break;
            // finger move
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (mode == Modes.DRAG)
                {
                    //single finger
                    matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.PostTranslate(e.Event.GetX() - start.X, e.Event.GetY() - start.Y);
                }
                else if (mode == Modes.ZOOM)
                {
                    //double finger
                    float newDist = Distance(e.Event);
                    if (newDist > 10f)
                    {
                        matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.PostScale(scale, scale, mid.X, mid.Y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.ImageMatrix = matrix;
        CheckScale();  //Limit zoom range
        CheckAlignment(); // Make sure picture won't go outside view
    }

    // calculate the distance of two points
    private float Distance(MotionEvent eventA)
    {
        float x = eventA.GetX(0) - eventA.GetX(1);
        float y = eventA.GetY(0) - eventA.GetY(1);
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    // calculate the middle point of two points
    private PointF Middle(MotionEvent eventB)
    {
        float x = eventB.GetX(0) + eventB.GetX(1);
        float y = eventB.GetY(0) + eventB.GetY(1);
        return new PointF(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    // limit maximum and minimum scaling
    private void CheckScale()
    {
        float[] p = new float[9];
        matrix.GetValues(p);
        if (mode == Modes.ZOOM)
        {
            if (p[0] < minScale)
            {
                matrix.SetScale(minScale, minScale);
            }
            if (p[0] > maxScale)
            {
                matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
            }
        }
    }

    // keep the image within the imageview
    private void CheckAlignment()
    {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.GetValues(values);
        imgUpLeft = new PointF((int)values[2], (int)values[5]);
        imgDownRight = new PointF((int)(btm.Width * values[0]) + imgUpLeft.X, (int)(btm.Height * values[4]) + imgUpLeft.Y);

        float dx = 0,
              dy = 0;

        if (imgUpLeft.X > viewUpLeft.X)
            dx = viewUpLeft.X - imgUpLeft.X;
        else if (imgDownRight.X < viewDownRight.X)
            dx = viewDownRight.X - imgDownRight.X;

        if (imgUpLeft.Y > viewUpLeft.Y)
            dy = viewUpLeft.Y - imgUpLeft.Y;
        else if (imgDownRight.Y < viewDownRight.Y)
            dy = viewDownRight.Y - imgDownRight.Y;

        matrix.PostTranslate(dx, dy);
    }
}
```